# How to use HashSet as DataSource in DataGridView (using INotifyPropertyChanged) C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, collections, datagridview

I am trying to implement data binding with in `DataGridView` witd data in `HashSet`. 
I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my model class like this ( I hava found this solution here on stackoverflow), but it still doesn't change the data grid view without reseting data source.

My model class

```
 class BookModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        private uint year;
        private uint pagesCount;
        private string series;
        private string publisher;
        private string author;
        private string language;
        [DisplayName("Book Name")]
        public string Name {
            get { return name; }
            set { SetField(ref name, value, "Name"); }
        }
        [DisplayName("Book Year")]
        public uint Year {
            get { return year; }
            set { SetField(ref year, value, "Year"); }
        }
        [DisplayName("Book Series")]
        public string Series {
            get { return series; }
            set { SetField(ref series, value, "Series"); }
        }
        [DisplayName("Book Pulbisher")]
        public string Pulbisher {
            get { return publisher; }
            set { SetField(ref publisher, value, "Pulbisher"); }
        }
        [DisplayName("Book Author")]
        public string Author {
            get { return author; }
            set { SetField(ref author, value, "Author"); }
        }
        [DisplayName("Book Language")]
        public string Language {
            get { return language; }
            set { SetField(ref language, value, "Language"); }
        }
        [DisplayName("Book Pages Count")]
        public uint PagesCount {
            get { return pagesCount; }
            set { SetField(ref pagesCount, value, "PagesCount"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When creating form I do

```
        bookContainer = new HashSet<BookModel>();
        dataGridViewBookList.DataSource = bookContainer.ToList();
```

And than on button click

```
            // Creating new book from user input
            bookContainer.Add(newBook);
```

But this only works if

```
            bookContainer.Add(newBook);
            dataGridViewBookList.DataSource = bookContainer.ToList();
```

It seems like a kind of "dirty solution" and INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't affect in this case.

Please suggest how to implement databinding to HashSet properly to notify gridview when data changed in collection (added,removed, modified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**- Consider using [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Option 2**- Consider using this class instead of `HashSet`:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis; 
using System.Data.Entity; 

namespace WinFormswithEFSample 
{ 
    public class ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource 
        where T : class 
    { 
        private IBindingList _bindingList; 

        bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection { get { return false; } } 

        IList IListSource.GetList() 
        { 
            return _bindingList ?? (_bindingList = this.ToBindingList()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This way you can also perform Master-Detail data binding. Suppose you have a Category class that has a `List<Product>` as childs, then you can make it work for Master-Detail databinding by changing `List<Product>` to `ObservableListSource<Product>`.

More Info: [Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for answer but I need to use HashSet in my case

Comment: Thank you for the help if there is no other way, I will do reseting each time, I need to use HashSet anyway